# Hystrix fallback method for redirect from controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix

I have a controller from which there is redirection to multiple other services. I was thinking of using hystrix fallback to redirect to a service not running page in case the service being redirected to is not running. But somehow the fallback is not working.

I have added @EnableCircuitBreaker to the main class. And using circuit breaker in my controller as below.

```
    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "serviceNotRunning")
    public ModelAndView jbotMS(final ModelMap modelMap, final HttpServletResponse response) throws JSONException {
        return new ModelAndView(ParentConstants.REDIRECT + this.jbotxMicroServices +"/");
    }
```

fallback method :

```
public ModelAndView serviceNotRunning(final ModelMap modelMap, final HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        System.out.println("Fallback called");
        return new ModelAndView(Constants.LOGIN_PATH);
    }
```

But somehow it is not working and each time I am getting the unable to connect page.

Is it not possible to use fallback on redirect or controller?

Comment: IIRC hystrix command doesn't work on a controller

Comment: I even moved it to the service class but it's still not working. I think the issue is with return new modelAndView. 

is there any way of handling redirect via restTemplate?

Comment: A service class should work. Shouldn't matter the return type